# In Symfony 2, Is there a way to delete user session (remember me) in case a device is stolen?

Tags: php, security, symfony, session

I have users that will use tablets to connect to my web application built with Symfony2. Remember me feature is great as it will not force them to log in every time.

My concern is if one of the device is stolen, the user session will remain active on that device because of the remember me cookie.

Is there a way for an admin user to log in and manually delete the user session that has the remember me?

Comment: In any case is better to set a determined lifetime for the "remember me" feature, with a decent time (some hours in most cases or some days, but it depends by your app needs).

Comment: That's a good question, I know by experience that deleting Symfony cache will normally reset all the sessions so maybe there's a way by looking into that.

Comment: A good approach is to force the user to reinsert the password on specific actions checking if is not fully authenticated (you can also invalidate his session with a redirect to the login page).

Comment: I din't try it, but theoretically you can make custom session handler that store sessions in database with additional field `user id`, later you can query session table and remove all sessions belongs to specific user.

Comment: I think it will be a combination of all comments unless someone happens to have a great idea that fix everything. Can't figure out why that issue is not of more concern in symfony.